# link sql database and oracle database into one SELECT query statement

Tags: java, sql

I want ask you about retrieve the information of one patient from different databases **(SQL and Oracle)** into one `SELECT` Query statement in java.

Databases different in the servers and the type.

Comment: SQL?  Do you mean MySQL or MSSQL?

Comment: "SQL and Oracle" doesn't make sense. Oracle **is** a "SQL database"

Answer (score 1):

It seams you are looking for ***Database link***, this is the best way you can do it i suggest to take a look of [CREATE DATABASE LINK](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm) and [Database Links](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm#ADMIN12083).

> into one SELECT Query statement in java

I don't think it will be easy to make, because you need some configuration behind, so you should to connect **two Databases** and in your case maybe **two DBMS** Oracle and another DBMS, so i suggest to learn about that.

Here is how to use [Database link from Oracle to SQL Server](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_database_link_sql_server_oracle.htm)

Here is a references [Database link from Oracle to PostgreSql](http://www.aide-oracle.net/2009/04/dblink-interroger-une-base-distante.html) (In french)